# What is the WHNF of a newtype and how does rseq work on a newtype?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, lazy-evaluation, newtype

Since `newtype`s are effectively removed during compilation, they don't have thunks, just values. So what happens if I ask for its WHNF using [`rseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/latest/doc/html/Control-Seq.html#v%3arseq)? For example in

```
Sum (lengthyComputation :: Int) `using` rseq
```

where [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v%3aSum) is defined as

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
```

will `lengthyComputation` get evaluated or not? Is it specified/documented somewhere so that I can count on it?

---

**Update:** Let me explain my doubts in more detail. Intuitively one says: "`newtype` is strict so clearly its WHNF is the WHNF of what's wrapped inside". But I feel this is a very imprecise shortcut and the reasoning is not so clear. Let me give an example:

For standard `data` types, WHNF can defined as a form where we know which constructor was used for constructing the value. If, for example, we didn't have `seq`, we could create our own

```
seqMaybe :: Maybe a -> b -> b
seqMaybe Nothing  = id
seqMaybe _        = id
```

and similarly for any `data` type, just by pattern matching on one of its constructors.

Now let's take

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

and create a similar `seqIdentity` function:

```
seqIdentity :: Identity a -> b -> b
seqIdentity (Identity _)  = id
```

clearly, nothing is forced to WHNF here. (After all, we always know what constructor was used.) After compilation, `seqIdentity` will be identical to `const id`. In fact, it isn't possible to create polymorphic `seqIdentity` such that it would force evaluation of a value wrapped inside `Identity`! We could define WHNF a of a `newtype` to be simply the value unmodified, and it would be consistent. So I believe the question is, how is WHNF defined for `newtype`s? Or is there no rigorous definition, and the behavior "it's the WHNF of what's inside" is simply assumed as something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the section on [Datatype renamings](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-740004.2.3) in the report,

> Unlike algebraic datatypes, the newtype constructor N is unlifted, so that N ⊥ is the same as ⊥.

Here

```
Sum ⊥ = ⊥
```

so the weak head normal form of a newtype is the WHNF of the wrapped type, and

```
Sum (lengthyComputation :: Int) `using` rseq
```

evaluates `lengthyComputation` (when the entire expression is evaluated, a mere binding

```
let x = Sum (lengthyComputation :: Int) `using` rseq
```

of course doesn't, but that is the same without the newtype constructor).

The [defining equations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2) for `seq` are

```
seq ⊥ b  =  ⊥
seq a b  =  b, if a ≠ ⊥
```

and hence

```
seq (Sum ⊥) b = ⊥
```

and in

```
seq (lengthyComputaton :: Int) b
```

the `seq` is required to find out (sorry for the anthropomorphism) whether `lengthyComputation :: Int` is ⊥ or not. To do that, it must evaluate `lengthyComputation :: Int`.

---

Re update:

`newtype`s are *unlifted*, that means that the constructor is not a value constructor semantically (only syntactically). Pattern-matching on a `newtype` constructor is, in contrast to pattern matching on a `data` constructor not strict. Given

```
newtype Foo a = Foo { unFoo :: a }  -- record syntax for convenience below
```

a "pattern match"

```
function :: Foo a -> Bar
function (Foo x) = whatever x
```

is completely equivalent to

```
function y = let x = unFoo y in whatever x
```

The match always succeeds, and evaluates nothing. [The constructor only coerces the type](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) and "pattern matching" on it un-coerces the type of the value.

`seq` is magic, it cannot be implemented in Haskell. You can write a function that does the same as `seq` for a `data` type, like your `seqMaybe` above, in Haskell, but not for a (polymorphic) `newtype`, because "pattern matching" on the newtype constructor is not strict. You would have to match on the constructor(s) of the wrapped type, but for a polymorphic `newtype`, you don't have them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I feel that the step "`newtype` is strict so its WHNF is the WHNF of what's inside" isn't precise. I modified the question and tried to express my doubts in detail.

Comment: It's not that `newtype`s are strict, it's that they are _unlifted_ that makes the WHNF propagate.

Comment: Expanded answer, does that clarify it more?